# What is the significance of the '50th Eater of Souls message'

Tags: terraria-mobile

I recently purchased Terraria for my iPhone, and I'm getting along just fine; I've got experience from console and PC. When I was in the corruption farming rotten flesh, an orange message popped up stating: `50th Eater of Souls killed`

The same thing then happened at 100. But this hasn't happened for any other mob that I've killed, I'm still very early on in the game so I've not seen many mobs yet.

I've looked around, and I found a [Wiki entry](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Banners_(enemy)) describing how a banner is dropped after every 50 kills of a specific enemy. I must, however, assume that this feature isn't yet implemented in the mobile version of the game as no banner dropped.

So I'd like to know the purpose of this message, and if it really means anything at all.

Comment: Just for future reference, you should use [the offical wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Terraria_Wiki) instead of the one you linked. The Wikia one is often inaccurate or out of date.

Comment: I've changed the link accordingly

Answer (score 5):

On the PC version, for every 50 kills you get on any specific monster type, you will get a notification in chat congratulating you on the achievement, and you'll also get a banner that provides a few minor bonuses against that specific monster type.

It appears that the automatic banner drop feature is not implemented in mobile, so you're only getting the congratulatory messages. They don't serve any purpose other than to help you keep track of how many of those monsters you've killed. (Banners only drop in mobile with a 1/200 (0.5%) chance from each enemy).

[Reference](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Banners_(enemy))

Comment: This hasn't happened for any other mobs though, and I've killed plenty of slimes, zombies, skeletons, bats, jelly fish and piranhas

Comment: After reading the article on the official wiki that you've linked I found that, if what you've said is true, then I should get the message for every mob.

Comment: I don't play the mobile version, so I don't know 100% for sure, but if you're only getting the message for one mob type, it's possible that the messages might be bugged, or perhaps not fully implemented. But yes, according to the wiki, you should be getting the messages for every type of enemy.

Comment: It could possibly be a bug in the game causing only like a select few enemies to display the kill message when you kill them.

Answer (score -2):

That's just a little award-type thing, it doesn't really have any relevance.

Comment: Hello there! Welcome to Stack Exchange, if you haven't already have a look at the tour page to help you get started. Also, I would recommend having a look at other questions and answers on the site to aid you in structuring your own